# When "binding" ItemsSource in xaml the ListView is blank, however if setting property directly the listview is populated?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been slogging away at this for ages and can't figure it out. All the other StackOverflow answers are marked as accepted but don't work so I'm sure I'm missing something!

I have a ListView inside a content page, that I simply want to bind to a property of List. The listview appears blank with the binding but DOES appear when I specifically set the ItemsSource after the web API returns its data - however, I want to do it property and bind it.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstGroupMembers" ItemsSource="{Binding groupMembers}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding = "10" >
                    < Grid.RowDefinitions >
                        < RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "20" />
                    </ Grid.RowDefinitions >
                    < Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        < ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
                    </ Grid.ColumnDefinitions >

                    < Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                        Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        WidthRequest="40" />

                    <Label
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row= "0"
                        Text= "{Binding Name}"
                        FontAttributes= "Bold"
                        VerticalOptions= "End"
                        />
                    < Label
                        Grid.Row= "1"
                        Grid.Column= "1"
                        Text= "{Binding Location}"
                        VerticalOptions= "Start" />
                </ Grid >
            </ ViewCell >
        </ DataTemplate >
    </ ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ ListView >
```

cHome.xaml.cs

```
public partial class cHome : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<listItemGroupMembers> _groupMembers; 
    public List<listItemGroupMembers> groupMembers
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupMembers;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupMembers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("groupMembers");
        }
    }

    async protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            //Set the binding context for the listview
            BindingContext = this;

            //We need to connect to the server, check the token and download the group info
            refreshFamilyInfo();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MG.Shared.Exceptions.ExceptionHandling.RaiseNewException(ex);
        }

    }

    async private void refreshFamilyInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            //return the process while we validate the token
            JObject JSON = await MG.Controllers.Group.getGroupInfo();
            if (JSON == null)
                throw new Exception("The JSON is null");

            //-----------------------------------------------

            groupMembers = new List<listItemGroupMembers>();

            JArray results = (JArray)JSON.getItemSafe("results");
            foreach (JObject child in results)
            {
                groupMembers.Add(new listItemGroupMembers { Name = child.ToStringSafe("FRIENDLY_DESCRIPTION").EmptyTo("Unknown"), ImageUrl = "face_36.png", Location = "Solihull" });
            }

            //lstGroupMembers.ItemsSource = groupMembers; -- THIS WORKS when uncommented. But i want it to bind!



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MG.Shared.Exceptions.ExceptionHandling.RaiseNewException(ex);
        }

    }


    public class listItemGroupMembers
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    new public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    override protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the `BindingContext` property from on appearing, `xaml.cs` file is by default the page where the lookups are made for binding, also `ContentPage` has the OnPropertyChanged method by default as it inherits from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. When you do the first change the binding code should start working. Make sure to update the collection on MainThread, Also if you are gonna make runtime changes in the list use `ObservableCollection` instead

Comment: You are binding to an empty List, then adding items to it.  Instead use an ObservableCollection - this will notify the UI when items are added.  List does not.

Comment: also, `listItemGroupMembers` has a `PropertyChanged` method but is not actually implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `ListView` to automatically update as items are added, removed and changed in the underlying list, you'll need to use an `ObservableCollection`. `ObservableCollection` is defined in `System.Collections.ObjectModel` and is just like List, except that it can notify ListView of any changes

```
public ObservableCollection<listItemGroupMembers> groupMembers { get; set; }
```

And when I test your code, the `OnPropertyChanged("groupMembers");` never triggered when I add items to `groupMembers`, that's maybe the reason that UI never update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i finally figured it out

For other people, the ObservableCollection was definately the right answer but also needed a few other bits:

```
private ObservableCollection<listItemGroupMembers> _groupMembers = new ObservableCollection<listItemGroupMembers>();
public ObservableCollection<listItemGroupMembers> groupMembers { 
            get {
                return _groupMembers;
            } set {
                _groupMembers = value;
            } 
        }
```

The list needed to be instantiated with the variable declaration (above) - creating a new list at runtime stopped it from working (I assume it created a new object that the list wasn't binded to)

The OnAppearing "BindingConext = this" section WAS needed otherwise it didn't work

No INotifyPropertyChanged interface or onPropertyChanged event was needed. It worked without it.

Thank you for your help everyone - really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This also works for me

```
if ((listView.ItemsSource as ICollection).Count != 0 && (listView.ItemsSource != null))
{
    listView.SelectedItem = ((List<Word>)listView.ItemsSource).Last();
}
```